# tcllib websocket: How to print received messages to a text widget

Tags: websocket, tcl, tk-toolkit

Here is the important part of my code:

```
set message_initialization_result ""

proc logMessage {msg} {
    upvar outputtext outputtext

    if { [string length $outputtext] > 0 } {
        if { [string length $msg] > 0 } {
            $outputtext insert end $msg
            $outputtext insert end "\n\n"
        }
    }
}

proc handler { sock type msg } {
    upvar outputtext outputtext
    upvar message_initialization_result message_initialization_result

    if {[catch {
    switch -glob -nocase -- $type {
    co* {
        logMessage "Connected on $sock"
    }
    te* {
        logMessage "Received:\n$msg"
    }
    cl* -
    dis* {
        logMessage "Disconnected"
    }
    }
    }]} {
        set message_initialization_result "$message_initialization_result handler"
    }
}

set sock [::websocket::open ws://127.0.0.1:10010 handler]

...
logMessage $message_initialization_result
```

`outputtext` is a variable that holds a text widget.

How do I get the handler to print the messages it receives to that text widget?
And how can I check if this handler is called at all? I tried provoking errors but it seems that they are all caught by a `catch` inside the websocket library.

Comment: Is it your intention that the `if` body should be executed only if there is an error running the `switch` command? If it ever gets executed, I think you'll find that it tries to get a value from `message_initialization_result`, which does not have a value to begin with. The whole assignment is pointless anyway, since the variable dies with the `handler` procedure when it ends.

Comment: You are right. I upvar'ed `message_initialization_result` and `logMessage`d it at a point where I can already use the websocket. Still I get nothing displayed. I'll update the code above.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `puts [info level 0]` at the beginning of `handler`?

Comment: I have no console output at all somehow with the tcl distribution I am using  (undroidwish vanilla). So puts will not do much for me

Comment: If you can't get any console output, can you open a file in the handler and `puts` the information there?

Comment: If you can open a console (`console show`) the output should show up there.

Comment: I tried some much and now it suddenly worked. I have no idea what it was... Maybe just the change from `upvar` to `global`of `outputtext` in `logMessage`. Thank you two very much for the hints. Especially the `console show` was useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm collecting a couple of points for posterity...

- For quick-and-dirty debugging, add the command `puts [info level 0]` to the beginning of those procedures you want to track. In this way you get to see every time the procedure is called, and what arguments it received.
- If you don't have a console in a Tk-based script (for instance on Windows) and thus can't see the output from `puts`, try opening the Tk console with `console show`.
- If you can't get output as above, try sending output to a file. If you can use `fileutil`, the command `::fileutil::appendToFile log.txt $msg` is perfect for light logging. Check out the options to the command.
- No `fileutil`? Try `set f [open log.txt a] ; puts $f $msg ; close $f`. Opening and closing the file every time keeps it flushed and means you don't need as much of intrusive injections and synchronizations.

Documentation:
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[console](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/console.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: I accept this. It does not solve the root problem which was that I used `upvar` instead of `global`, but it at least helps to find out what is going on if you don't have a console at first.